# TransactionAttribute.REQUIRES_NEW not starting new transaction in EJB bean using container managed transaction

Tags: java, transactions, ejb-3.0

```
@Singelton
public Class className {
    
    @Resource
    private TransactionSynchronizationRegistry tsr;
    
    @Resource 
    private Transaction 
    
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public method_A () {
    
         System.out.println(tsr.getTransactionStatus()); // prints 0 
    
         method_call_which_throw_persistence_exception(); 
    
         System.out.println(tsr.getTransactionStatus());  // prints 1
    
         method_B();
    
    }
    
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public method_B () {
          System.out.println(tsr.getTransactionStatus());  // prints 1
    }                
}
```

Note:

- Transaction status `0 = active`.
- Transaction status `1 = markedForRollback`

As i have attached the code above, 2 methods are present in a Ejb singelton bean which is using container managed transaction. `method_A` starts which have `TransactionAttribute` as `REQUIRED` thus  `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry` prints transaction status as `0` in starting.

After a method call which throw runtime exception transaction status becomes `1` automatically. But when a `method_B` which have transaction attribute as `REQUIRES_NEW` is called still `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry` prints `1`.

As per my understanding it should start a new transaction and the trasaction status should show as `0` in `method_B`?

Answer (score 3):

A direct call on the bean method from a method of the same bean does not go through the transaction interceptor and hence no transaction attribute check is done.

There are 2 ways to solve this:

```
@Resource
private ManagedExecutorService mes;


....
mes.execute(()->method_B());
....
```

This will go through the interceptor/proxy and also being in a different thread will automatically start a new transaction. the drawback here is that if the new transaction fails the one in `method_A` will not be rolled back as they are in different threads